# Trying to run Sheet.getData() and getting a NPE

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to run the method `Sheet.getData()`, and am getting a NPE. From what I can get from the Javadocs, I needed to have requested a data range in order to not get a null value, but I cannot get any information on how to request a data range.

```
Sheets service = new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
        .build();
ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId, range).execute();

Spreadsheet spreadsheet = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId).execute();
List<Sheet> sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
Sheet sheet = null;
for(Sheet s : sheets)
    if(s.getProperties().getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("GSheets API Sheet"))
        sheet = s;

List<GridData> data = sheet.getData();
//System.out.println(data.size());
```

I'm doing it this way because I need to get a cell's background color, so if anyone can help me do this in a different way, I'd be open to other methods.

Comment: Is that Google Sheets?

Comment: Could you copy you stacktrace?

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at SheetsQuickstart.main(SheetsQuickstart.java:83)`

Line 83 is when I tried to get the size of `data`, but `data` is null.

Comment: I can't see a line where you try to get the size of data in you code. Could you add a // comment on line 83?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the exception is thrown at the commented line, when it isn't commented.

It means the `data` object is null, which means sheet.getData() returns null. So I guess something must actually be wrong with the infos you use to create your spreadsheet. The options are multiple. You should check the way you obtain the credentials and also the value of spreadsheetId.

Comment: So I need to do setRowGroups() before I get the data?

Comment: No, you need to make sure `sheet` is not null when you call a method on it. Calling a method on a null object is forbidden.  So you can test nullness before you call a method on an object: `if (t!=null) {t.doSomething();}` or make sure beforehand the object is not null, which you didn't in your example. At the end of the for loop, you can' be sure sheet is not null.

Comment: I'm not trying to prevent a method from running if it is null, I'm trying to prevent it from being null in the first place.

Comment: I still don' know on which line you get your exception, but assuming it is on `sheet.setRowGroups()`, it means your loop is incorrect, because at the end of the loop, it seems that sheet is still null.

Comment: the `sheet.setRowGroups()` was a mistake that I forgot to remove. Sorry! The source code above is what my code actually is. Including the line on which the error is occurring (in hindsight, I probably should have included it initially).

Comment: I edited my answer. You could try to execute your code step b step and try to look what happens precisely.

Answer (score 0):

`s.getProperties().getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("GSheets API Sheet")` is never evaluating to `true`, so `sheet` is never set to a non-null value.

In other words, your workbook has no sheet named "GSheets API Sheet".

Always check to make sure your objects are not `null` before trying to call methods on them!!

Comment: I already ruled that out. I ran multiple tests to see if sheets was null after the for loop, and it was not, I did have a sheet named that. From what I can tell, `Sheet.getData()` can return a null value if I do not assign a range, which I have no idea how to do without explicitly getting values.

Comment: I am well aware what a NullPointerException is, but I am wondering if anyone can tell me how to prevent `Sheet.getData()` from returning a null value in the first place, because `sheet` is not null.